# How to provide a default path for Log4j file inside Linux Environment?

Tags: web-applications, log4j

a very good day to all .

I am asking a question , out of curisioty , may be this seem to be a foolish question also .

This is my log4j.properties file for a Application which will be in production very soon .

log4j.rootCategory=Info, A1

## A1 is a DailyRollingFileAppender

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.file=D:/MyWEBLogs/MyWEB.log
log4j.appender.A1.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.append=true
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-22d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m%n
```

As you can see the file path i have mentioned here is D:/MyWEBLogs/MyWEB.log .
(This works fine under Windows Environment )

But our Application will be taken as a war file and deployed inside Tomcat inside Linux Environment .

Inside Linux Environemnt , we are not  sure about the path  (That is whaere this tomcat resides there ...) and also as a user we have got limited permissions , like  to create a file ---etc

So now my question is , what should be the best default path to be put  in below line , so taht it runs  anywhere in linux Environemnt  , no matter where it is placed

```
log4j.appender.A1.file=D:/MyWEBLogs/MyWEB.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be `${user.home}/appName/MyWEB.log` , user generally has right to write in home dir

Comment: Thank you , ${user.home}/appName/MyWEB.log  will this work ?? because i think i don't have a user with my name created under our Linux Environment .Please tell me ,  Will this still work ??

Comment: {user.home} is system property it will take the home directory of the user under which the application is running, and yes it will work

Comment: This is working with glassfish server and ubuntu machine for me.                   
 But it is not working with TomEE server and ubuntu machine. Have you any idea?