# log4j xml configuration in linux

Tags: linux, log4j

```
 <appender name="RollingFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
 <param name="Append" value="false"/>
 <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1KB"/>
 <param name="File" value="/mylog.log"/>
 <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3"/>
 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}:%p %t %c - %m%n"/>
 </layout>
 </appender>
```

This config works in linux, it is used by java called from shell script.
I need to put mylog.log to ${home} dir.
How should it be like? 
${home}/mylog.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system property `${user.home}` should do what you want as explained in [How to provide a default path for Log4j file inside Linux Environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036061/how-to-provide-a-default-path-for-log4j-file-inside-linux-environment)